# Webtrends - utilization report

Tags: webtrends

Want to find out how many files were downloaded on my website out of total number of files. eg: i have a million pdf files and people have downlaoded only 100,000. this is 10% utilization.

I tried downloaded files report but it shows only top 1000 files. is there a way to get the complete count. ie number of fiels downloaded atleast once.

is it possible to get this count without re-analyzing the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, no, it is not possible without re-analyzing the profile and the report. You have to adjust the so called "Table Size Limit", which limits the number of elements to analyze and the number of elements to show in the report.

Example: You have 1 Mio. Pages within your website. The report analysis limit is set to 250.000 pages, so after that, new pages will not be recorded and count by webtrends. The final report you see within reports will only show you the top 2.000 pages.

You need to increase the Table Size Limits and re-analyze. If you not use Webtrends On-Demand and you still have the logs, a re-analyze will not effect your page views licenses.